# call popup.html javascript function from background page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to call javascript function in popup.html from background page ( in chrome extensions)?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is not possible to get a direct reference to the popup page, the main reason is that the page might not be open when you try and call it.

You have to use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) to pass a message between popups and background pages.

I would ask is there a specific need to have the function in the popup and not have it re-factored into a separate shared file.

Comment: I wanto modify popup depending of the content of the page.

Comment: I would place the logic in the background page, and in the onload event on your popups document>body get the information from the background page.  You can also change the physical background page by using: setPopup http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/browserAction.html#method-setPopup

Answer (score 2):

Would be best to place that functionality in a Background page instead and within your popup you can do:

```
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
bkg.someBackgroundPageFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the contributions. I found [this reference](http://markashleybell.com/building-a-simple-google-chrome-extension.html) which solved the problem.